# What did I do wrong here?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, parent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE5ml.png)
moveing left bone
[image]
moveing right

I dont know what went wrong here, I made the left rig first and mirrored it, parent it with the mesh automatic weight, and some how the right hand wont move, when I move the right hand. Only when I use the left one it moves. the Legs dont have any problems. (anatomical right and left). I used this Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBYb1YmaOMY . If anyone could help me that would make me happy.

Comment: i cant tell like this , please give the file through https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5aoBqVMn" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5aoBqVMn/)

Comment: @SHikhaMittal ...

Comment: ha its 12 here , will check tommorow :)

Comment: @SHikhaMittal ...

Comment: sry wasnt able to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is the use of asymmetrically named pair bones. Try to change the right hand bone name to "Hand.R".

[image]

Comment: thank you and how can I make, that my hands move 
individually? @tetii

Comment: nvm, I got it, thank you (*￣3￣)╭